# Using apache's FFT to convert a .wav file to freq array

Tags: java, fft

Here's what i have so far:

```
InputStream is = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:/users/barnao/desktop/uotm.wav"));
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);

short[] shorts = new short[bytes.length/2];
ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(shorts);

double[] vals = new double[shorts.length];
for (int i = 0; i < shorts.length; i++)
    vals[i] = (double) shorts[i];

FastFourierTransformer fft = new FastFourierTransformer(DftNormalization.STANDARD);
Complex[] freqs = fft.transform(vals, TransformType.FORWARD);
```

However i'm getting an error message that the input isn't a power of 2...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.math3.exception.MathIllegalArgumentException: 31,590,166 is not a power of 2, consider padding for fix
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: You don't want to FFT the whole file - normally you do a sequence of overlapping fixed size FFTs (e.g.N=2048), aka sequence of STFTs, aka spectrogram.

Comment: Ah ok, are there any standards for sample size or distance of STFTs? I have an array of shorts, so for example (FFT 1024 elements, at intervals of 512?)

Comment: I realise it's not a particularly helpful answer, but it *really* depends on what your objective is. FFT may not even be the right tool here.